# For Spring boot version greater than 2.7.5 is java 17 required or we can use jdk 11 or 8

Tags: spring-boot

For Spring boot version greater than 2.7.5 is java 17 required or we can still use jdk 11 or 8 if so why this is not mentioned in release notes .

However for Spring boot 3.0 it's clearly mentioned in the documents that the  minimum required version is java 17 https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0.

Can the Spring team clarify

Answer (score 6):

The Spring Boot 2.x generation requires at least Java 8. This is [documented in the system requirements section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements) of the reference documentation. As new versions of Java have been released, support for them has be added. Spring Boot 2.7.10, the latest Spring Boot 2.7.x release at the time of writing, supports Java 8 to 20 inclusive.

The Spring Boot 3.x generation requires at least Java 17. This too [is documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements) with Java 17 to 20 inclusive being the currently supported versions.

Answer (score 1):

For spring boot version below that 3x, you can use Java8 or Java11, but if you are planning to move to Spring boot 3x, you need atleast Java17 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not from Spring team. Just a user of Spring.

For me it is clear: if a minimum version of Java is not required - why should it be mentioned in the release notes? Way back it was mentioned however when the minimum version started to be 1.8. Since then no changes. It means we could use all 8+ versions. Until Spring 3 were it is 17+.